# Reading the input and searching it in a csv file

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
read -p "Introdueix la zona d'origen:" zona
tail +3 cars.csv | sort -n -k2 -t';' > consum
nlinies=`wc -l < consum`

i=1
while [ $i -le $nlinies ]
do
    head -$i consum | tail -1 > linia
    if [ $zona = '-k9' ] ; then
        echo "MPG: `cut -d';' -f2 linia`  Origen: `cut -d';' -f9 linia`"
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
   
rm consum 2> /dev/null
rm linia 2>/dev/null
```

I want the program to read the input and search for the input within a file and print the other details of the input. Is there any way I can do this through Shell script?

Comment: Are you just trying to print the 2nd and 9th columns of lines which match a particular string in a comma separated file?

Comment: Yes. Actually, the user will enter a country and the program should go to the file and search the input country which is one of the countries that are there in the 9th column. So I want to print the consumption of the car from the country which is on the same line but it's in the 2nd column

Comment: Look at the edit I did.  No code change, just a bunch of spaces to indent the code.  Much easier to read and figure out the scope blocks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. a sample cars.csv and the output you want for a test case.

Comment: Rather than computing the number of lines and then iterating over `head|tail`, just write `while read line; do ...; done < consum`.  You can also avoid the temp file completely and just pipe sort directly to the loop `sort ... | while read line; do ...`.  And you can also split the line with `sort ... | while IFS=\; read a b c d e f g h i j k; do ...`

Comment: Couple hints.  You ask the user for his input, store it in zona.  You can then use `grep` to extract all lines that contain `zona` from cars.csv.  Then extract the info you need, by column with `cut`, like you do.  You should use `$( )` instead of back ticks.  Lastly you can paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ it will point out a couple syntax points.

Comment: Hints no2.  `cut -d';' -f2 linia` should be `echo $linia | cut -d';' -f2`.  `linia` is a variable, not a file.  So you have to echo the value of linia and pipe it to `cut`.  This entire line could be done with `awk -F ";" '{print "MPG: " $2 "  Origen: " $9}'`